# Visual Studio Tools For Apache Cordova - Missing Android Support Package

Tags: android-support-library, taco, tools-for-apache-cordova

I've been trying to install the Visual Studio TACO dependencies for quite a few hours now and I can't seem to get past the following error. It's the last error in the dependency check and it will not go away.

> Android Package: extra-android-support One or more required packages are missing.

I've installed more SDKs and additional tools than are necessary via the docs located here:

[Install Tools For Apache Cordova - Visual Studio](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/)

I have the Android Support Repo installed (Ver 43), Along with SDKs 19, 21, 22, and all of the Build Tools from 25.2.5 down to 19.1 and even included the obsolete 19.03 package.

I'm about to ditch TACO for a pure Cordova CLI project and handle kicking off my own emulator and just running my api in VS, because right now the additional frustration isn't really winning me over.